# Testing lambda in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I set up my lambda function like so:

[image]

I want to deploy on a api. When I set-up the api as a rest api, I try to test it, like below:

[image]

I get the below error:

```
Request
/
Latency
43
Status
200
Response body
{"errorMessage": "'base'", "errorType": "KeyError", "requestId": "f2e47d2a-5662-422c-9b34-3d6fed8e0319", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in lambda_handler\n    mathResult = math.pow(int(event['base']), int(event['exponent']))\n"]}
Response headers
{
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-65992065-8da5d12e56efe91d47bbf28e;Sampled=0;lineage=63116542:0"
}
Log
Execution log for request 359c5a53-c10b-466e-9570-c3e6f4fb4d61
Sat Jan 06 09:41:57 UTC 2024 : Starting execution for request: 359c5a53-c10b-466e-9570-c3e6f4fb4d61
Sat Jan 06 09:41:57 UTC 2024 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /
Sat Jan 06 09:41:57 UTC 2024 : Method request path: {}
Sat Jan 06 09:41:57 UTC 2024 : Method request query string: {}
Sat Jan 06 09:41:57 UTC 2024 : Method request headers: {}
Sat Jan 06 09:41:57 UTC 2024 : Method request body before transformations: {
    "Base": 2,
    "Exponent": 3
}
```

Anyone know how to test it correctly? Do I need to add something else to my request?

Comment: keys used in python dictionary are `case-sensitive` in code you are using `base` and `exponent` but in your Request body, you are passing `Base` and `Exponent` hence your code throws a `KeyError` because it's not able to find lower case keys in the event it's receiving :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues here. One, as Frosty pointed out in their comment, you are passing upper case letters but looking for lowercase letters. The second issue is that you need to convert the "body" part of the event object to a dictionary before you can access the fields. Third, you aren't passing a valid json string to 'json.dumps()'.

You can review this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event) for the format of the event object that is sent to your Lambda function from the API GW.

The code segment will look something like:

```
body = json.loads(event.body)
mathResult = math.pow(body['base'], body['exponent'])

return {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": 'Your result is ' + str(mathResult)
}
```

Note I am assuming that the body of the message will be sent as:

```
{"base": 2, "exponent": 3}
```

In other words, the keys will be in all lowercase letters.